# create custom workflows through the net

Tags: wcf, workflow-activity

I have created a WPF rich application that allows users to create customs workflow activities (create, edit, save, run), which is working ok.

I have also created a **WPFBrowser application** version, and I published it to a IIS web server. In IIS lies the problem, I just found some files:

- ApplicationName.exe: The executable assembly application file.
- ApplicationName.xbap: The deployment manifest.
- ApplicationName.exe.manifest: The application manifest.

Is there a way to also hold my other project ressources on IIS (for example: icons, .cs classes, activity-designers, etc.)?

Comment: I thought that the only thing that gets served is the XAP. Any such resources would need to be bound in the XAP.

Comment: This is what I do see , OK , thank you for the answer John